# does b64_pton() work if input contains special characters? I am using it in C code

Tags: c, embedded

I have c code where b64_pton() is failing is when input passed contains special characters. Without special characters its working fine.

Comment: Pardon? Context? Understand?

Answer (score 2):

[`b64_pton`](http://www.opensource.apple.com/source/OpenSSH/OpenSSH-95.1.5/openssh/openbsd-compat/base64.c) converts base64 to binary.  There should be no 'special characters' in your [base64](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) strings.